# I am not able to reach the company's database when bot is hosted on microsoft azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework, bots

I have created a Microsoft bot for my bachelors project, I am working with a company to do so. The microsoft bot is supposed to reach the company's database. I am using Microsoft Azure to host the bot. While testing the bot from my Visual Studio project everything works fine(If I am connected to the company's network where the database is). Now when I deploy my bot to microsoft bot, the bot is unable to reach the database

I am trying to reach the database using the AdomdClient nuget package. I am trying to connect to an Analysis services server. This is how I set the connection string. Data source is the public IP and after the coma is the port where the analysis services is available.

`AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection("Data Source=xx.xxx.xx.xx,xxxxx;Catalog=someCatalog");`

My supervisor told me to find out where the microsoft bot is hosted(if it's an azure website or not because they whitelisted the some of the domains, like azurewebsites.net)

The bot is returning this error since it didn't find any resource.

````
Sorry, it looks like something went wrong.Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaSR.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "AdomdClientNetCore" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.```
````

Comment: Then do what your supervisor told you to do.

Comment: Are you using LUIS?

Comment: azure relay https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_zAJZC_8Yk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find where the bot is hosted, you will want to look at the bot channels registration. This will show either as a Web App Bot or Bot Channels Registration. You can search for it by using Bot Service as type. [image]

After finding he correct bot, go to it and find the settings section. Under there, you will find the bot endpoint. This is the url where the bot is actually listening at.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot connect to a company's on premise database from Azure unless it is publicly accessible or you azure web app uses VNet that's linked to your company's network through a VPN(site to site) or you are using Azure Relay.